# Matching data (recursive) in multiple tables

Tags: python

Below is the table structure:

Table1:

```
A1
D1
B2
A5
C8
B5
```

Table2:

```
TargetCol SourceCol

A1      E8

B2      C9

E8      F2

C9      D2

F2      A8

D2      E2

C8      G2

G2      K4
```

Rewriting the problem to make it more clear:

Looking for a code to generate an output:

Dataframe1:

A1  E8

E8  F2

F2  A8

Dataframe2:

B2  C9

C9  D2

D2  E2

Dataframe3:

C8   G2

G2   K4

Many Thanks for your support !!!

Comment: are these database tables or something else?

Comment: big size excel sheets

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see the output requirement now.

Comment: Any help on this?